# JQuery DatePicker close behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a page that has a JQuery datepicker on it that is meant to show dates in mm/yy format. I didn't write the initial JQuery and I'm not very familiar with it so this may be a simple issue but when a user clicks the 'Done' button the datepicker disappears for a second then opens back up as if the user had clicked in the textbox again.

The code used to instantiate the datepicker is:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        },
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                //month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                month = datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5);
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
            }
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker").mousedown(function() {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggle();     
    });
});
```

After googling around for a while I added the mousedown handler and that made it so that when you click anywhere on the page away from the datepicker then it closes as expected but if you click the done button it doesn't actually close the datepicker.

Comment: When you say "when a user clicks the 'Done' button the datepicker disappears for a second then opens back up as if the user had clicked in the textbox again" is that the bug or the intended behavior?

Comment: Thats the bug. I assumed when the user clicked done then the intent would be for the datepicker to set the textbox to whatever date they had selected and for the datepicker to go away so the user can see the rest of the controls in order to type in whatever other information that is required.

Comment: This only seems to be an issue in IE as well. Both chrome and FF act as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected. I do not see the bug in the fiddle I set http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/ZQTqe/

Comment: could the validation on the form be causing it to get focus again? or how do I check the version of JQuery that my predecessor used to make this? any idea why it would work as expected in fiddle but not on a live server?

Comment: The logic conclusion is that the scenario is not the same. You have something else happening on the server scenario. You mentioned a form validation process, this might be it. Try debugging it, put a `debugger;` clause in the first line of `beforeShow` and take a look at the stack trace to see who is calling it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I eventually just removed the datepicker from the page completely. It was being used to get the expiration date of a credit card so I just switched it to use two combo boxes instead of a datepicker. I don't know what was causing the issue or where to even start looking so I'm just marking it off as a lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is the problem:

```
$("#datepicker").mousedown(function() {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').toggle();     
});
```

It toogle show/hide a form on mousedown, your datepicker will be hidden automatically when you click a date or done button. Try to remove this from your code.

Comment: before I included those lines it would never go away unless you clicked in the textbox and used the tab key to move to the next control. Clicking anywhere on the page caused the datepicker to blink off then back on again. I've fixed my initial problem and I think this was just a matter of me being unfamiliar with the code and the person who wrote it doing something incorrectly. I've removed the datepicker in question and found another way of acomplishing what I needed.

Comment: I tought that the handler is attached to the datepicker not to input box.

Comment: The datepicker extends the input box. So I think of them as one in the same(datepicker can't exist without the input box, input box is just a text field without the datepicker). As far as the handler goes I don't know which control that belongs to. It doesn't matter I'm sure it was just a mash up of coincidences that caused my initial problem and I have no inclination to track it down any longer since splitting the date out to two different fields was the most intuitive way to have the user input the information to begin with.